# Can i pass a integer argument to DW.Table.Select

Tags: powerbuilder

I have stored procedure which requires two string and an integer argument to execute. I'm trying to execute the stored procedure by

```
MySQLString="DataWindow.Table.Select=~"CALL MYPROC('" + strarg1+ '",  "' + intarg + "' ,'"  + strarg2+"')~""                 
dw_1.Modify(lsSQLString)
dw_1.Retrieve()
```

This is throwing a compile error like `Incompatible types in expression: string, integer`

Can anyone explain if `DataWindow.Table.Select` will support passing integer arguments like `intarg` above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `strarg1` and `strarg2` are both of `string` type, and `intarg` is an `integer`, you cannot concatenate them with `+` to make the string `MySQLString`.

That's what the compiler is trying to tell you with

> Incompatible types in expression: string, integer

You have to convert the `integer` in `string` with `string(intarg)` :

```
MySQLString="DataWindow.Table.Select=~"CALL MYPROC('" + strarg1+ '",  "' + string(intarg) + "' ,'"  + strarg2+"')~""
```